# How can I reset pgfplots settings?

Tags: pgfplots

Suppose I have a document which has a `\pgfplotsset{...}` part in the preamble. Further suppose that in the main document I want to do a pgfplot inside of an environment `\begin{myenv}...\end{myenv}`.

Is there a way to reset all settings to default values locally, i.e. inside of the particular `myenv` environment?

Comment: Put the `\pgfplotsset` inside the environment would do that, I think. Anyway, please add an MWE to make your question clearer.

Comment: I'm afraid there's nothing out-of-the-box to do that. `\pgfplotsset` (or `\tikzset` or any other key-value interface) is just a fancy wrapper around `\def`, which changes the value of some macro to a user-defined value, so all scoping rules apply. You'd need some mechanism to “remember” the original values and then apply them inside your `myenv`. I'd suggest you change your approach and create a style with the contents of the global `\pgfplotsset` and then use that style in all pictures but the ones in `myenv` (or override that style inside `myenv`).

Comment: If you have settings that you want to apply to all but a few plots, you may just store them in a style that you use in most of the plots.